# Retrieve user photo with Office365 REST API

Tags: rest, outlook, exchange-server, office365, outlook.com

I am using Office365 REST API to [get details about my contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations#ContactoperationsGetcontacts), but I noticed there is no information about user's profile picture in the response.
I suppose I need to retrieve in some other way, but I wasn't able to figure out how.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now, the REST APIs don't support contact photos or user profile photos. We're working on adding that soon. Keep an eye on our [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/) or follow me on @JasonJohMSFT) for announcements regarding new features.

UPDATE: The User Photo API is now in preview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/photo-rest-operations

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest in Office 365 REST APIs!  We don't yet support retrieving user's picture but it is in the works.  Stay tuned for an update from us on http://blogs.office.com/dev/ when this feature is ready.

In the mean time, you could use our Exchange Web Services SOAP API to retrieve the user's picture.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190905(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more info.  Let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am moving to Graph API now, since it looks providing more information. I hope there will be profile pictures there! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would lose your time because there is no image property returned bu graph api. I already checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2017:
There is now a REST'ful way to get both of those pictures:

Contact: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations#get-contact-photo-and-metadata

User : https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/photo-rest-operations#get-photo